# FFT of signal data with windowing, overlapping and averaging

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, window, overlap-add

This is my first ever question here so the help is really appreciated.

I am performing FFT on a signal. I want to perform windowing, 50% overlapping and averaging to the signal. There is a function `scipy.signal.welch` to perform this automatically but the output is in power spectral density. I want the output in magnitude and phase shift both, but from power spectral density only magnitude is achievable. Is there a way to compute phase shift from power spectral density or a simple way to do this analysis in the form of FFT rather than in power spectral density?

I know how to apply windowing in python but I do not know how to do overlapping and averaging manually.

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft, fftshift, fftfreq
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import scipy.fft

data = pd.read_csv('lucid_1p34g_1024fps_5mins.csv')

ref = data.loc[:,"Input 0"]
sensor1x = data.loc[:,"Input 1"]
sensor1y = data.loc[:,"Input 2"]
sensor1z = data.loc[:,"Input 3"]

fs = 1024
blockSize = 1024

f, Pxx = signal.welch(sensor1z, 1024, window='hann', nperseg=blockSize, 
                     noverlap=512)

plt.plot(f, Pxx)                # power spectral density plot
plt.show()

"""Manual Calculation"""

N = len(sensor1z)
n = np.arange(N)
T = N/fs
freq = n/T

window = np.hanning(N)
f1z = fft(sensor1z)                       #fft transform of input 3
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(f1z))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "phase shift"? That terms is usually associated with systems, not signals. The phase of a signal is not particularly easy to define, so you need to be specific about what exactly you want to calculate.

Comment: I assumed he just meant the phase response, but I could be wrong...

Comment: "Response" implies system to me (like in impulse response). Relative phase between two signals is very meaningful. Absolute phase of a signal not so much, especially if you segment the signal.

Comment: Right, I mean absolute phase, not phase response. I assumed because of "I am performing FFT **on a signal**". And agreed, as mentioned at the top of my answer, no sense averaging...

Comment: Are you looking for a short-term Fourier transform? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html

Comment: The signal data is actually response of a system under shaker vibration.

Comment: @EricCanton no not short term fourier transform

Comment: @EricCanton thank you for your help, I was able to write a code manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to perform windowing, 50% overlapping and averaging to the signal

This makes sense for magnitude, but not for phase.

> Is there a way to compute phase shift from power spectral density

No. The PSD is computed by averaging magnitude spectra together, so there is no phase information.

> or a simple way to do this analysis in the form of FFT rather than in power spectral density

Yes, what you want is simply the phase of `f1z`:

```
plt.plot(freq, np.angle(f1z))
```

---

Depending on what information you want from the phase, you might want to unwrap / normalize the phase:

```
plt.plot(freq, np.unwrap(np.angle(f1z)))
# or
plt.plot(freq, np.unwrap(np.angle(f1z)*180/pi))
```

**EDIT per the OP's request**

What you are asking is a coding question: you already know how to perform fft and get magnitude and phase. What you want is doing this on overlapping segments of your signal, then averaging.

Again, not going to write the code for you but here would be an approach:

1. Define segment length $N$. To do this, figure out what frequency resolution $d_f$ you're happy with, and compute $N = \text{ceil}(f_s/d_f)$
2. Define overlap $R$: you can experiment with this, common ones are $R = 1/2$ or $R = 1/4$ for example.
3. Define a window function of length $N$. A [Hann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function) window for example. Or if you just want a rectangular window, go on to step 4 and dis-regard the `np.multiply` operation.
4. Now here comes the coding part:

   - do fft on `np.multiply(data(0:N-1), window(0:N-1))`.
   - extract magnitude and phase and store both somewhere
   - advance by `R`: do fft on `np.multiply(data(R:N-1+R), window(0:N-1))`
   - extract magnitude and phase and store both
   - advance by `R`: do fft on `np.multiply(data(2R:N-1+2R), window(0:N-1))`
   - extract magnitude and phase and store both
   - etc

   This can be done in a loop. Once you have all your magnitude and phase arrays, just average them together.

FYI, this is just a naive implementation of the Short Time Fourier Transform that @EricCanton mentions in his [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85308/63763).

Comment: How do I perform overlapping and averaging on f1z?

Comment: "This makes sense for magnitude response, but not for phase response". You can use welch's method `plt.plot(f, Pxx)` for the magnitude, and `angle(f1z)` for the phase.

Comment: You're asking now for custom code. I'm not going to write custom code for you that does overlapping and averaging, since that's the point of having functions such as `welch`. (Also, you can find that easily on google ;) ). If you want to write custom code from scratch, first study what [welch's method](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Welch_s_Method.html) is, try to write it yourself, and compare the output of your custom implementation vs the output of the built-in `welch` function. If you get stuck somewhere, come back and ask for help!

Comment: But as far as your original question(s), those have been answered. Good luck!

Comment: The welch method gives the output in form of power spectral density. I want the output in the form of magnitude like the one obtained by numpy.fft, but the problem I am facing is to perform overlapping and averaging.

Comment: @AniqueAhmedKhatri I edited my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: thank you for your help, I was able to write the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a short-term Fourier transform? This computes an FFT in a sliding window, giving an array of complex numbers from which you can extract magnitude and angle/phase.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

data = pd.read_csv('lucid_1p34g_1024fps_5mins.csv')

ref = data.loc[:,"Input 0"]
sensor1x = data.loc[:,"Input 1"]
sensor1y = data.loc[:,"Input 2"]
sensor1z = data.loc[:,"Input 3"]

fs = 1024
blockSize = 1024

freq, ts, Zxx = signal.stft(
    sensor1z,
    fs=fs,
    nperseg=blockSize,
    noverlap=512,
    window='hann'
)

# Zxx is a numpy array of complex numbers
# get magnitude
Zxx_mag = np.abs(Zxx)
Zxx_phase = np.angle(Zxx)
```

Comment: Function STFT does not perform overlapping and averaging which I require for the output.

Comment: it performs overlapping. You'd only have to do the averaging manually, which is a basic coding problem, but it's not the purpose of this website to write custom code for you. `Zxx_mag` and `Zxx_phase` have everything you need for what you're trying to achieve.